# BlackJack Class Difficulties

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm trying to simulate the dealer of a game of blackjack, and I'm really confused.

Basically, I'm using a deck of cards that only consists of J, Q, K, A, and 2-10 to simplify this stuff, rather than using an ordinary card deck setup.

I realize all of this is pretty messy, I've been working with classes for all of 3 hours.

```
class Deck:
    '''Simulates a deck of cards.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Deck() -> Deck
        Creates a deck of cards'''
        self.Deck = ['J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '10']

    def __str__(self):
        '''str(Deck) -> str
        Returns string showing number of cards left'''
        output = str(len(self.Deck)) + ' cards'
        return(output)

    def shuffle(self):
        '''shuffle(self) -> Deck
        Shuffles deck.'''
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.Deck)

     def draw(self):
        if len(self.Deck) > 0:
            return(self.Deck.pop(0))
        else:
            return(-1)

    def add(self, card):
        self.Deck.append(str(card))

class BlackJackPlayer(Deck):
    '''Represents someone playing blackjack.'''

    def __init__(self, Deck):
        self.BlackJackPlayer = Deck
        self.hand = ''
        self.value = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hand

    def clean_up(self):
        self.BlackJackPlayer = Deck
        self.hand = ''
        self.value = 0

    def get_value(self):
        for x in self.hand:
            if x != ',':
                if x not in range(1, 11):
                    if x != 'A':
                        self.value += 10
                    else:
                        if (self.value + 11) > 17:
                            self.value += 1
                        else:
                            self.value += 11
                else:
                    self.value += x
        return(self.value)

    def hit(self):
        Deck.shuffle(self.BlackJackPlayer)
        card = Deck.draw(self.BlackJackPlayer)
        return(card)

    def play_dealer(self):
        while BlackJackPlayer.get_value(self) < 17:
            self.hand += BlackJackPlayer.hit(self)
            print(self.hand)
            if BlackJackPlayer.get_value(self) < 17:
                self.hand += ','
        if BlackJackPlayer.get_value(self) > 21:
            return('BUST')
        else:
            return
```

For some reason, whenever I call jack.play_dealer(), it'll stop too early because it thinks the hand is already over 21.

For example:

```
>>> deck = Deck()
>>> jack = BlackJackPlayer(deck)
>>> jack.play_dealer()
7
'BUST'
>>> jack.get_value()
40
```

I'm guessing something's wrong with my get_value(), but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't finished docstringing my stuff. So, shuffle() shuffles the deck, draw() draws a card and removes it from the deck, add() allows you to add a card to the deck, get_value() gets the value of the hand, hit() draws one card from the deck, and play_dealer() sims a dealer.

Comment: Why are you using `BlackJackPlayer.get_value(self)` instead of the more usual `self.get_value()`? e.g. why use unbound methods instead bound methods on the instance?

Comment: You are muddling things further by giving the `Deck` instances a `Deck ` attribute, and the `BlackJackPlayer` instances a `BlackJackPlayer` attribute, the latter being a `Deck` instance.

Comment: I really have no idea how to do most of this, sort of learning as I go. Thanks! I noticed that no matter what the hand is, get_value() will always return 50. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are, see my answer.

Comment: Actually, why are you adding commas to the hand?

Comment: I just wanted to separate the cards with a comma, but I just took that out.

Comment: As a stylistic point - `return` is a statement, not a function - it does not need (or benefit from) parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Deck` cards are all strings:

```
self.Deck = ['J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '10']
```

Note the `'2'` and `'3'`, etc. strings.

Yet you try to treat them as integers:

```
for x in self.hand:
    if x != ',':
        if x not in range(1, 11):
```

`x` will **never** be in `range(1, 11)`, because all your values are strings. So the above `if` statements are **always** `True`.

The next part is:

```
if x != 'A':
    self.value += 10
else:
    if (self.value + 11) > 17:
        self.value += 1
    else:
        self.value += 11
```

When 'number' cards are drawn, the `not in range(1, 11)` is still true, they are not equal to `'A'`, so you count all cards as value 10.

You'll need to rethink how to handle the number cards here. You can test for alphanumeric ordering:

```
if x >= 'A':
```

would work for your numeric cards too, as all numbers sort before capitals in the ASCII standard. Use that instead of the `not in range(1, 11)` test.

Next problem is that you are then trying to add up the value using strings when the cards are numeric:

```
else:
    self.value += x
```

but that adds up strings; a string value is **always** greater than numbers (in Python 3, comparing strings and numbers raises an error).

Use `int()` to sum actual numbers:

```
else:
    self.value += int(x)
```

Now at least you have something working:

```
>>> deck = Deck()
>>> jack = BlackJackPlayer(deck)
>>> jack.play_dealer()
A
A,A
A,A,9
'BUST'
>>> jack.get_value()
60
```

But this is still too high. That's because you use `self.value` to store the calculation but *never reset it*. You keep on adding for each new calculation.

Use a local variable instead of `self.value`:

```
def get_value(self):
    value = 0
    for x in self.hand:
        if x >= 'A':
            if x != 'A':
                value += 10
            else:
                if value > 6:
                    value += 1
                else:
                    value += 11
        else:
            value += int(x)

    return value
```

Now the game works as expected:

```
>>> jack = BlackJackPlayer(Deck())
>>> jack.play_dealer()
J
JA
JAA
JAA6
```

Comment: Ok, I did what you told me to do, but get_value still gives me 44 even thought the hand is 8,Q

Comment: get_value works fine when I try it in the shell without the 'self.' but it won't give me the correct number when I run it from the module.

Comment: @user2540878 The problem is that you need to reset the self.value to 0 at the beginning of get value because you reevaluate the entire hand. So you just keep adding up from last hands.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just realized that if I do what you said in this answer, get_value will evaluate 10 separately as 1 and 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I just made get_value add 10 to value whenever x == '1', and when x == '0', it made no difference.

Comment: Ah, you are indeed treating the hand as a string instead of a list and then each card should be only *one* character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should replace the logic for getting the score. The problem is that your treating strings as integers and that you reevaluate the entire hand without resetting the value.

```
def get_value(self):
    self.value = 0 # reset for reevaluation
    aces11 = 0
    for x in self.hand.split(','):
        x = x.strip() # strip off excess whitespace
        if x in '2345678910': # numeric
            self.value += int(x)
        elif x == 'A': #An ace
            self.value += 11
            aces11 += 1
        else: # a face card
            self.value += 10
        #check to reduce aces if greater than 17
        while self.value>17 and aces11>0:
            aces11 -= 1
            self.value -= 10
    return(self.value)
```

Comment: Not greater than 21 because I want the dealer to stop being allowed to hit if he goes over 17

Comment: So you want the dealer to treat the Ace as 1 when greater than 17 if Ace is 11, so that he'll hit again. I can accept that.

Comment: There is still a problem. What if Ace is first. It'll be scored as 11 and then if you get a 9 next there's know logic to set 11 to 1 and calculate again. I've edited this post.